# Understanding an integral approximation

Tags: integration

Working on some instance of the stationary phase (precisely on [these notes](https://www.math.unl.edu/~scohn1/8423/intasym4.pdf)), I bumped into a problem I don't understand. Say $f$ is a smooth function, and that we are considreing $\lambda \to \infty$. Can we write
$$\int_{c-\varepsilon}^{c+\varepsilon} e^{\frac{i\lambda}{2} (t-c)^2} dt =  \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{\frac{i\lambda}{2} (t-c)^2} dt + O(\lambda^{-1})?$$

I don't understand why this is true. If this was on a compact domain, I could justify it by the stationary phase method (that is to say, integrating by parts), but is there a simple argument in this case? Is there a way to write down a dyadic  approximation? Is this integral on the right hand side really convergent?

Thanks for any clarification, I think I miss something that should be trivial when I read these notes...